# Javascript XML parsing error

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am trying to parse with Javascript a XML file returned by a PHP script but something is not working and I don't know what.
The PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
   include ('database_connection.php');

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("elements");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);


    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $country = $_GET['country'];

    $query = "select * from elements where elementId=any(select elementId from citycategoryelements where cityId="
            . "any(select cityId from city where name='$city' and country='$country') and categoryId=any("
            . "select categoryId from categories where name='$category'))";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // Add to XML document node
        $node = $dom->createElement("element");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
    }
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    ?>
```

The XML returned looks something like this:
XML Example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elements>
    <element name="first_name" address="first_address"/>
    <element name="second_name" address="second_address"/>
</elements>
```

Then I try to process the XML file with Javascript:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("element")[0].getAttribute("name");
        alert(name);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getElements.php?category=" + encodeURIComponent(category) +
                 "&city=" + encodeURIComponent(address[0])
                 + "&country=" + encodeURIComponent(address[1]), true);
                //xmlhttp.open("get", "file.xml", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When I try to run the code the alert doesn't appear. Also if I try to alert the xmlDoc I get `null`.

You can see that I have this comment `//xmlhttp.open("get", "file.xml", true)`

If I use it instead of 
the first `xmlthttp.open` it works(as you may guessed file.xml is just a plain xml file that looks like the example above). I really don't know what the problem may be, I am sure that the PHP script returns a valid XML file. If someone could help me that would be great, thanks in advance!

**edit**

also I forgot to say that if I use Firebug and

I get something like this:

> TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: By the way you should be really careful of SQL injection. Unless this is a very internal or test applicaiton of some sort.

Comment: You can try to log the content of `xmlDoc` in the callback function, just after the `var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;` line

Comment: `console.log(xmlhttp);` What do you get? Also, perhaps it would be a lot easier to send JSON instead of XML

Comment: @user574632 _JavaScript_ is case sensitive

Comment: if I use console.log I get Document

Comment: try with `console.dir()` if you are using IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(...)[0]` is *undefined*

This means that `xmlDoc` is defined, because it could invoke `getElementsByTagName`, but that the return from `getElementsByTagName` did not include a property `0`, meaning `getAttribute` failed because `x[0]` was *undefined*.

This suggests that your *XML* did not parse as you expected; as you show the output generated `<element>` tags.

Review the `xmlDoc` in your console and you should be able to see an error message there.

---

That said, I cannot reproduce your error

```
var xhr, b, uri;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);
    console.log(this.responseXML);
};

b = new Blob(['<?xml version="1.0"?>\n\
<elements>\n\
    <element name="first_name" address="first_address"/>\n\
    <element name="second_name" address="second_address"/>\n\
</elements>'], {type: 'text/xml'});
uri = URL.createObjectURL(b);

xhr.open('GET', uri);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: @fifth - Please make sure you find your browser's console and ask for instructions if you don't. `alert()` is a fairly limited debugging tool.

Comment: @Paul S - thanks for the help it was a problem with the XML parsing, at the very beginning it had 2 spaces so it was invalid. Thanks again and also thanks everyone for trying to help me and giving me usefull advices!